# Eclipse refactor to add superclass to type hierarchy

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, hierarchy, superclass

I've read the different options that are listed in the manual for refactoring [here](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-menu-refactor.htm) but I don't think what I want is there.

I have a project with many batch jobs which are classes that extend org.quartz.Job to which I of course I can't make changes. As I find myself writing a bunch of the same code in each job to do things specific to my system, it becomes apparent that I should have an abstract class that is the parent of all my batch jobs and does those system-specific tasks, let's call that org.mycompany.MySystemJob which will extend org.quartz.Job

I would've imagined that this refactoring would be readily available, where all the classes that are directly extending from class A are made to extend from a new class B which is created by the refactor and made to extend A.

I've considered "extract superclass" but this is actually a lot simpler, since the methods would be from a single source and the "extract superclass" refactor asks you to manually add all the "sibling" classes which in this case are all real siblings already.

I know I can find all such classes in the type hierarchy and then change a single line on each. It is not that hard, sure, but it seems to me that saving this kind of manual work is exactly what refactoring is supposed to be.

Anyway, maybe I am just missing what is there. I hope so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to **create a class/interface with the same qualified name** as the library class/interface which can not be changed. If this class/interface is moved or renamed, all references that originally related to the class/interface of the library are automatically updated to this newly created class/interface.

Consider also to use [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) instead.

Comment: Very creative trick indeed. Thank you. This does take care of searching for the implements and extends and changing them to the new class. However, I think this goes overboard since it changes all the uses of the base class / interface thinking it will no longer exist. I suppose one could manually choose what to change. I will come back in a few days and mark this as an answer if there is no better option. I do think this could be a refactor type of its own. It is certainly useful though.

Comment: @Brian Yeah, that's right, e. g. references to static methods will also be updated. I hadn't thought of that. When doing a rename/move refactoring, in the refactoring dialog you have to do a preview and unselect all non-_extends_ references.